# Insert comma after certain byte range

Tags: perl, bash, csv, awk

I'm trying to turn a big list of data into a CSV. Its basically a giant list with no spaces, and the rows are separated by newlines. I have made a bash script that basically loops through the document, awks out the line, cuts the byte range, and then adds a comma and appends it to the end of the line. It looks like this:

```
awk -v n=$x 'NR==n { print;exit}' PROP.txt | cut -c 1-12      | tr -d '\n' >> $x.tmp
awk -v n=$x 'NR==n { print;exit}' PROP.txt | cut -c 13-17     | tr -d '\n' | xargs -I {} sed -i '' -e 's~$~,{}~' $x.tmp
awk -v n=$x 'NR==n { print;exit}' PROP.txt | cut -c 18-22     | tr -d '\n' | xargs -I {} sed -i '' -e 's~$~,{}~' $x.tmp
awk -v n=$x 'NR==n { print;exit}' PROP.txt | cut -c 23-34     | tr -d '\n' | xargs -I {} sed -i '' -e 's~$~,{}~' $x.tmp
```

The problem is this is EXTREMELY slow, and the data has about 400k rows. I know there must be a better way to accomplish this. Essentially I just need to add a comma after every 12/17/22/34 etc character of a line.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please, show us examples of the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many many ways to do this with Perl. Here is one way:

```
perl -pe 's/(.{12})(.{5})(.{5})(.{12})/$1,$2,$3,$4,/' < input-file > output-file
```

The matching pattern in the substitution captures four groups of text from the beginning of each line with 12, 5, 5, and 12 arbitrary characters. The replacement pattern places a comma after each group.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk, you could write

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS="12 5 5 12"; OFS=","} {$1=$1; print}'
```

The `$1=$1` part is to force awk to rewrite the like, incorporating the output field separator, without changing anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is very much a job for [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @widths = (12, 5, 5, 12);
my $offset;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  for my $width (@widths) {
    $offset += $width;
    substr $line, $offset, 0, ',';
    ++$offset;
  }
  print $line;
}

__DATA__
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

**output**

```
123456789012,34567,89012,345678901234,567890
```